# max_stack_depth on PostgreSQL trigger execute

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I have very simple trigger and trigger function. Trigger function should insert GUID in every row after insert operation.

SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "USERS"
(
  id integer,
  guid uuid,
  name text
)
```

Trigger function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertGUID() RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    INSERT INTO "USERS" ("guid") VALUES (md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid);
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER example_trigger BEFORE INSERT ON "USERS" EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertGUID();
```

But after after every insert. Like:

```
INSERT INTO "USERS"(name)  VALUES ('foo1');
```

I am getting error: `max_stack_depth`

`CONTEXT:  SQL: "INSERT INTO "USERS" ("Joe") VALUES (md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text)::uuid)"`

UPD: I am getting same problem even if I use `BEFORE INSERT`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `insert` fires the trigger which inserts a new row, which then fires the trigger, which inserts a new row, which fires the trigger, which inserts a new row, which fires the trigger which inserts a new row.... (you get the picture).

You want to *change* the new row, not *insert* a new one. So your trigger function needs to be like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insertGUID() 
  RETURNS trigger AS
$BODY$BEGIN
    new.guid := md5(random()::text || clock_timestamp()::text;
    return new;
END$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

For this to work the trigger itself has to be defined as `before insert`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER example_trigger 
    BEFORE INSERT ON "USERS" EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertGUID();
```

---

<sup>Unrelated, but: you should *really* avoid quoted identifiers (`"USERS"`). They are much more trouble than they are worth it</sup>

Comment: Strange, but it's look like it's work same even with `BEFORE` http://snag.gy/hyth5.jpg

Comment: but on my screenshot is `before`. Or am wrong? I will try check all again

Comment: @user1432751: I have no idea what that screen shot is supposed to show me. The problem with the endless recursion has nothing to do whether it's a before or after trigger. But _changing_ the column value will **only** work in a before trigger.

Comment: I checked all my code. I am getting same error even if I use `BEFORE INSERT`.

Comment: @user1432751 Again: did you remove (replace) the `insert` statement from the _trigger function_?

Comment: my function now look like:
`CREATE TRIGGER createguid
  BEFORE INSERT
  ON "USERS"
  FOR EACH STATEMENT
  EXECUTE PROCEDURE insertguid();`

Comment: That's your _trigger_, not your trigger _function_. Please do apply the **complete** code from my answer.

Comment: You forgot `)` after `::text` also after acception your function instead my after attempt to insert data I am getting error that `new` does not have value